# how to check if imagestream is existed in openshift container platform with jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I ran this code to check and delete the imagestreams in Openshift

```html
 openshift.withCluster("${CLUSTER_NAME}") {
                        openshift.withProject("${DEV_ENV}") {
                            if (openshift.selector('imagestreams', '${imagestream_name}').exists()) {
                                openshift.selector('imagestreams', '${imagestream_name}').delete()
```

then I ran this

```html
openshift.withCluster("${CLUSTER_NAME}") {
                        openshift.withProject("${DEV_ENV}") {
                            openshift.apply(openshift.raw("create -f '${imagestream_name}'.yaml"))
```

to create new imagestream from local yaml file but it end up with this error

```html
ERROR: raw command [create -f 'imagestream-test'.yaml] returned an error;
{err=Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "imagestream-test.yaml": imagestreams.image.openshift.io "testimagestream" already exists
```

Is there anyway to check if the imagestream is already in openshift ?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `apply` instead of `create`? `oc apply` will create a resource if it doesn't exist or update if it does.

```
openshift.withCluster("${CLUSTER_NAME}") {
                        openshift.withProject("${DEV_ENV}") {
                            openshift.apply(openshift.raw("apply -f '${imagestream_name}'.yaml"))
```